# aws cloudwatch agent for ecs service discovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

**The question:**

Does anyone now how to configure cwagent to make it only create service discovery files for prometheus?

**Why:**

I am trying to find an approach to monitor my amazon ECS services with prometheus. So I'd prefer to do this via some sort of "service discovery". Unfortunatelly, prometheus cannot do this from scratch. However, I found this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights-Prometheus-Setup-autodiscovery-ecs.html

Well, cloudwatch agent has the worst documentation I ever seen.

Does anyone now how exactly should I configure cwagent to make it only create service discovery files for prometheus?

Ideally, I want to run it as a side container in a kubernetes pod with prometheus. The only thing cwagent should do is to hit API (in different accounts) via roles and then create sd file for prometheus to scrape.